# wont let me run node . in vsc terminal (making discord bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js, onedrive

So im facing a problem where for me to cd to desktop i have to cd to onedrive first. Also in visual studio code when i try to get my bot online by doing node . nothing happens or no errors.

Well for the onedrive problem i disable it (well i think i did.) Still had to cd into onedrive to cd into desktop. So then i tried running account on local which didnt work also. For node . i tried googling it and watching videos nothing worked.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.client();

const token = '(my token)';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot is Online');
})

bot.login(token);
```

nothing happen this is what the terminal said when trying to get my discord bot online in vsc.
 PS C:\Users\dfkj1\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot> node .
PS C:\Users\dfkj1\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot>

Answer (score 0):

Try to run node with the actual filename instead of just '.'. `node filename.js` will allow node to know which file you would like to run.

As for your desktop problem, I don't really know where to start on that one. Saying that you have to go through One Drive before Desktop does not make sense. If you have a directory named Desktop inside of OneDrive, then maybe that is the reason. Normal directory structure should be C:\Users\username\Desktop for the desktop folder and C:\Users\username\OneDrive for One Drive. You might want to check that there isn't a Desktop folder inside of the OneDrive folder and that's what you are using.

Taking a closer look at the file you posted, it looks like you `import Discord`, then create the `client` variable with `new Discord.create()` but then never use `client`.  Are the commands with `bot` in them supposed to be `client.on` and `client.token(token)`

Something like this works, just tested it on my machine.  Don't have the token so it fails at authentication.  You also want to use `Client` instead of `create` and capitalize Client in the `Discord.Client()` line.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = '(my token)';

client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot is Online');
})

client.login(token);
```

Comment: yeah turns out it was in desktop but im not to sure how to get it out tried deleting it but kept getting error pop ups. Btw the file name was index.js so yeah node still didnt work

Comment: I just took a closer look at your code, see the edit about the client variable and it never being used.

Comment: also it looked like you were using the incorrect method for creating the new bot.  The correct method was `Discord.Client()` and not `Discord.create()`.  I tested the code in my reply and it did work up until the auth part.